# Mongoose is not ignoring space in regex?

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I want to do simple regex search, but for some reason following query returns nothing

```
Assessment.find({"name": {
   $regex: /.*Chris Baker.*/,
   $options: "si"
 }
})
```

while direct in mongodb console :
`db.deals.find({ 'name': { $regex: /.*Chris Baker.*/, $options: 'si' }})`

return expected result.

Tried different regex:
`new RegExp('.*' + queryString + '.*')`

`/.*Chris[\\S]Baker.*/`

Without any success. Pretty sure issue in space. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what might be desired. My guess is that, we like to collect all chars, then search for `Chris Baker`, which we might be able to do so, using an expression similar to:

```
([\s\S].*?)(Chris Baker)?
```

[image]

[image]

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/czTlTf/1)

```js
const regex = /([\s\S].*?)(Chris Baker)?/gm;
const str = `Some text we wish here then Chris Baker then some other textSome text we wish here then Chris Baker then some other textSome text we wish here then Chris Baker then some other textSome text we wish here then Chris Baker then some other text`;
const subst = `$1$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```